# How do I get CSV output when querying for IAM Groups and Users?

Tags: powershell, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-powershell

First time poster here.

I have created a small script that outputs group membership in AWS.

I have got the script to the point that it outputs the desired results but I require help getting the data in a readable format into a csv file.

```
$awsgroupnames = Get-IAMGroups  
$accountname = Get-IAMAccountAlias 

foreach ($awsgroupname in $awsgroupnames) {
    $groupuser = Get-IAMGroup -groupname ($awsgroupname.GroupName)
    $usernames = $groupuser.users | select UserName 
    write-host $accountname ($awsgroupname.groupname) ($usernames.username)
    }
```

The output looks like this.

```
Account Alias - Group - User

aws-dxxxd-mxxer axx-admin xxhie sxxwj bhxxwk hxxv rxxerd cxxx axxw-sf-msdsmt

aws-dxxxd-mxxer aws-casesupport 

aws-dxxxd-mxxer aws-readonly gixxxi mxxxxilj kxxng bxxnst txxxgd rxm kxxxrs

aws-dxxxd-mxxer billing-admin bsdffdk crcccdi

aws-dxxxd-mxxer Billing_Access

aws-dxxxd-mxxer vdc-axxxs mxxxab rxxxd cxxxmi aws-srxxxc-mxxt

aws-dxxxd-mxxer vpc-axxxn mxxxab mxxxj mxxxnr
```

How can I get this to export out to a csv in the following format?

```
Account Alias - Group1 - User1

Account Alias - Group1 - User2

Account Alias - Group1 - User3

Account Alias - Group2 - User1

Account Alias - Group2 - User2

Account Alias - Group3 - User1

Account Alias - Group4 -  Blank for no user
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution for powershell v3.0+ that groups the data in a way that makes extraction to CSV a bit simpler.

Code:

```
$alias = Get-IAMAccountAlias

Get-IAMGroups | % { 
  $group = $_;
  (Get-IAMGroup -groupname $_.GroupName).Users | % { 
    [pscustomobject]@{ 
      Alias = $alias; 
      GroupName = $group.groupname; 
      UserName = $_.UserName
    } 
  }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation > mycsv.csv
```

Example Output:

```
"Alias","GroupName","UserName"
"myacct","admins","myuser1"
"myacct","admins","myuser2"
"myacct","users","myuser3"
```

This script:

- iterates the output of Get-IAMGroups to get each GroupName
- iterates the output of Get-IAMGroup to get each user, and their UserName
- For each user, stores the Alias, GroupName, and UserName in a [PSCustomObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscustomobject(v=vs.85).aspx) with properties of the same name.
- Pipes the output collection of PSCustomObject to `ConvertTo-CSV` with `-NoTypeInformation` set to get the content in CSV format. Note here that if you want to change the delimiter, there is a `-Delimiter` flag that you can specify.
- Redirects the output to `mycsv.csv` to write the file out to your file system

A quick note from your attempt that probably gave you trouble: Stay away from using `Write-Host` to output data beyond your terminal; `Write-Host` does not write to the output stream. Here's a good [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) on the subject for further reading.